# PHP query subtraction

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to subtract the accepted bid which is an int from the job table and subtract from the credit from customer table but for some reason it updatedes credit row as -21 rather than 78 as accepted bid is =22. Any ideas why this is?

tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bjbe.jpg

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'config.php';


$id = $_SESSION['login_user'];
$jobid    = $_POST['job_id'];
$poster_id    = $_POST['poster_id'];
$accepted_bidder    = $_POST['accepted_bidder'];
$accepted_bid    = (int) $_POST['accepted_bid'];

$query = "SELECT credit FROM `customer` WHERE email_adress = '$id'";

$result = $conn->query($query);

//echo $result;
//echo $accepted_bid;
$updated_credit = (int)$result- $accepted_bid;
//echo $updated_credit;


$query2   = "UPDATE job SET start_escrow = '1' WHERE job_id = '$jobid'";
$success = $conn->query($query2);

$query3   = " UPDATE customer SET credit = '$updated_credit' WHERE email_adress = '$id'";
$success3 = $conn->query($query3);

$poster_id = $_POST['poster_id'];

if (!$success) {
    die("Couldn't enter data: ".$conn->error);

}
 header("location: myjobs.php");

echo "Thank You For Contacting Us <br>";

$conn->close();




?>
```

Comment: Which one is line 22? Why didn't you put a semicolon in the line where you do the subtraction?

Comment: Put ';' after "$updated_credit = (int)$result- $accepted_bid"

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after `$updated_credit = (int)$result- $accepted_bid`

Comment: Learn debugging. `var_dump($result)` __will show__ you that it is not `22`.

Comment: do you know why it is not 22 though? result should be 100. 100-22 is 78 not -21?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic PHP error:

You're missing final `;` at the end of line

```
$updated_credit = (int)$result- $accepted_bid
```

...it should be

```
$updated_credit = (int)$result- $accepted_bid;
```